# How to rollback a migration in Flyway Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, flyway

I just made a migration `file.sql` to add a new table to the database, and I ran the `flywayMigrate` command `sbt flywayMigrate`. Now I realised I missed adding two columns to the same table. I have an option to write another migration, but I don't want to increase the number of migrations when I can rollback and change the migration I just made to create a table and add two more columns to it. Can you tell me how do I rollback some number of migrations and change them, and run `sbt flywayMigrate` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to re-run whole migration. There's a table which flyway uses for metadata and I think it is called `schema_version`. You can set the last applied migration id (there are some hashes to be set IIRC, but you will be able to figure them from error messages, if they don't match) and flyway would pick up from there.

Comment: https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how describes how it works in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Flyway FAQ](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#downgrade) rollback scripts are not supported.

You have options to:

- restore your database from backup
- drop and recreate the database rerunning all the migration scripts
- manually rollback the migration and remove its record from metadata table

Comment: Just connect to database and run appropriate DDL to remove added tables/columns and revert any other changes you made.